# Issue connecting to thin from nginx

Tags: sockets, nginx, thin

In our stack we have a connection from nginx which is passing data to a thin server via sockets. The config file are the same in our test and training environments and the communication was working fine, but something has changed. One is working but the other is not. I'm guessing this is come sort of permissions issue, but I wasn't involved in the orginal setup so can't be sure. Is "unix:" a standard name for a socket connection and would any additional setup be required here:

This is the section of the nginx conf file:

```
upstream thin_cluster {
  least_conn;
  server unix:/tmp/thin.0.sock;
  server unix:/tmp/thin.1.sock;
  # Add additional copies if need more Thin servers
  server unix:/tmp/thin.2.sock;
  server unix:/tmp/thin.3.sock;
}
```

Nginx error log:

`2017/05/18 12:03:45 [crit] 1737#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/thin.3.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.82.206.61, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1                       ", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/thin.3.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "pptr3", referrer: "http://pptr3/console`                       /"

```
2017/05/22 10:49:44 [info] 4717#0: *29 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

Permissions for all these sockets are the same in both environments also:

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -ltr thin.?.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 rhoconnect rhoconnect 0 May 22 04:02 thin.0.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 rhoconnect rhoconnect 0 May 22 04:02 thin.3.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 rhoconnect rhoconnect 0 May 22 04:02 thin.2.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 rhoconnect rhoconnect 0 May 22 04:02 thin.1.sock
```

I'd like to pass something to these sockets to test it's working as expected but not sure how this can be done - telnet or echo | nc but not sure of the syntax or whether to expect a response?

Comment: The socket didn't exist when request failed so the thin process wasn't running at the moment. It is impossible to tell why it wasn't running from the information you provided

Comment: Thin process is running, what information would help?

Comment: You can check `thin` logs for any errors/restarts. Also having some process monitoring helps.

Comment: Thin has been restarted several times while trying to resolve. No errors in thin as communication is not getting that far

Comment: You probably need to increase logging level for thin